# I have trouble when I try to insert datas into database in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database

I'm trying to insert datas into a table in MySQL like below.

```
create database scottDB character set utf8 collate utf8_general_ci;

use scottDB;

create table mvc_bbs(   bNo int(3) not null auto_increment primary key,/*MEMO = Oracle: sequence*/
    bName varchar(20),
    bSubject varchar(80),
    bContent varchar(300),
    bDate datetime default current_timestamp,/*MEMO = Oracle: */
    bHit int(3) default 0,
    bGroup int(3),
    bStep int(4),
    bIndent int(4) );

insert into mvc_bbs(bNo, bName, bSubject, bContent, bDate, bHit, bGroup, bStep, bIndent) values(0, 'test','testです','こんにちは', last_insert_id(), 0, 0, 0); /*MEMO = Oracle: currval*/
```

However, whenever I tried, I can only see this message.

> Error Code: 1136. Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

What should I do?
I already read similar questions and answers, but I still have no idea.

Comment: You have 9 columns but values only 8

Comment: To Jens: Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should review your `SQL`:

1. you have `datetime` type but you want to fill it with `int`.
2. You have auto increment field, so No need to enter manually.

Show you one insert example:

```
insert into mvc_bbs(bName, bSubject, bContent, bHit, bGroup, bStep, bIndent) values('test','testです','こんにちは', last_insert_id(), 0, 0, 0);
```